# what is the return value of Bytes.compare?

Tags: haxe

According to:

http://haxe.org/api/haxe/io/bytes

There is a function Bytes.compare that returns an Int. What does this in mean? I tried to compare 2 Bytes object that were equal and I got 0 back. And for 2 different I got -529068432.

So it seems the function returns 0 for equal Bytes and something else otherwise. But just asking, what is the "offical specification"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is similar to the compare argument we give to [Array.sort](http://haxe.org/api/array). In this case, it kind of returns

- 0 if x == y
- >0 if x > y
- <0 if x < y

where x is the caller, y is the other Bytes.

Just a tip, you can always check the source code ([Bytes.compare's](http://code.google.com/p/haxe/source/browse/trunk/std/haxe/io/Bytes.hx#127)) if something is unclear.

Comment: ok thank, that works... btw... on these pages: http://haxe.org/api/haxe/io/bytes there is not a whole lot of docs, is it possible to contribute some docs to those pages somehow?

Comment: Sure! It is a wiki, which you can log in and then use the 'edit' button at the bottom of any page.

Comment: Hoping some sees this.. :) No I don't get it, I registered and logged in, and it seems I can comment on the whole class, but if I want to contribute docs for what the individual functions do, is that possible?

Comment: The edit button is right [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/andy-li/8280933232/). It is not user-friendly. Hope it will be improved too.

Comment: Aha... I missed it... And it looks a bit disabled to, but ok now I know... :) I made an edit there too, check what you think, if ok I'll write some more one-liner docs like that for therapeutic purposes..